# partitioning a range of sorted elements into adjacent groups

Tags: c++, sorting, c++11, c++17, stl-algorithm

I have a sorted list of items below.  I need to determine how to pick [inclusive, exclusive) item pairs from this list such that the difference between them exceeds some fixed value (for example 5 in the example below).

This should therefore result in partitioning the list into adjacent ranges (no element left out).

I figured out a brute force way of doing this (**[see live COLIRU demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/19c2a373d6c188fc)**), but I am sure there must be a more elegant solution and I am probably missing some edge cases (for example 1 a list containing a single value should result in the empty pair).  I was thinking that some variant of the stl range algorithms, `std::adjacent_find` or a combination of `std::lower_bound/std::upper_bound` could be used to determine these inclusive/exclusive pairs - for example using or some range based search in a loop or some sort - but I cannot figure it out.

The live searches the values `{ 100, 104, 108, 112,  116, 120 }` resulting in the following non overlapping ranges.  Note that the last pair (the difference is 4 (which is < 5) is a special case (see the code).

```
[100,104),[108,112),[116,120)
```

The code to do this is as follows:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <experimental/iterator>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> elements = { 100, 104, 108, 112,  116, 120 };
    std::vector<std::pair<int, int>> result;
    auto current = elements.begin();
    while (current != std::prev(elements.cend())) {
        auto next = std::next(current);
        while (((*next - *current) < 5) && (next != std::prev(elements.cend()))) {
            ++next;
        }
        // consider edge case where we are at the end of the list
        if (next != std::prev(elements.cend())) {
            result.emplace_back(*current, *std::prev(next));
        } else {
            result.emplace_back(*current, *next);
        }
        current = next;
    }
    std::transform( result.cbegin(), result.cend(), std::experimental::make_ostream_joiner(std::cout, ","), 
       [](const auto& next){ return std::string("[") + std::to_string(next.first) + ',' +  std::to_string(next.second) + ')'; } );  
}
```

Comment: Is it a problem that `108` and `116` got used twice?

Comment: @SirGuy No the groups are overlapping, think of the resultant pairs as [first, second)

Comment: @SirGuy Thanks for your feedback, I clarified the question with some edits - hopefully it is a little clearer now

Comment: This doesn't seem to me to be a brute force way of finding this, from what I can tell this will run in `O(n)` on a sorted list, which seems pretty ideal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
auto next = std::next(current);
while (((*next - *current) < 5) && (next != std::prev(elements.cend()))) {
    ++next;
}
```

In a *sorted* list, we are looking for the first element *at least* 5 bigger than our current element right? That's precisely what [`std::lower_bound`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/lower_bound) is for - which does a binary search instead of a linear one:

```
auto next = std::lower_bound(std::next(current), elements.end(), *current + 5);
```

Combine that with fixing your loop condition to go until the *end* of the list rather than one before the end (which just... looks wrong and needs some serious justification), and the whole body can just be:

```
while (current != elements.end()) {
    auto next = std::lower_bound(std::next(current), elements.end(), *current + 5);
    result.emplace_back(*current, *std::prev(next));
    current = next;
}
```

---

Side-note. This:

```
std::transform( result.cbegin(), result.cend(), std::experimental::make_ostream_joiner(std::cout, ","),·
   [](const auto& next){ return std::string("[") + std::to_string(next.first) + ',' +  std::to_string(next.second) + ')'; } );
```

Does not really seem better to me than, say, this:

```
bool first = true;
for (auto const& [first, second] : result) {
    if (!first) std::cout << ',';
    first = false;
    std::cout << '[' << first << '',' << second << ']';
}
```

YMMV. I know people like saying "no raw loops", but I rarely see `transform` lead to readable code....